# Select how many distinct values there are in a column and display them

Tags: php, mysqli, backend

I have a table in my database called names and each row inside this table has a class, as follows:

| Name | Class |
| --- | --- |
| John | Class-1 |
| Isabel | Class-2 |
| Mark | Class-1 |
| Gabriel | Class-2 |
| Mike | Class-2 |

As you can see, I have *class-1* and *class-2* repeat. What I want to do is get how many *distinct* classes there are (that is, in the example, class-1 and class-2) and for each class there are, I want to display the names corresponding to that class separately in different divs. So the output I want is:

```
<div>
 John
 Mark
</div>
<div>
 Isabel
 Gabriel
 Mike
</div>"
```

My current code is returning this: `Class-1Class-1`

when the second `Class-1` should be `Class-2`;

the code I've got so far:

```
$query = "select distinct class from names order by class";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
foreach($array as $class) {
  echo $class;
}
```

the code above is just a test to see if I was getting the correct "classes" in "class", but apparently I am not.

Comment: Well if you select DISTINCT you wont get all the rows and therefore wont get all the peoples names

Comment: So your current code does not return any rows woth `Class-2` in at all??

Comment: @RiggsFolly (I don't know how to reply directly so I'll just tag you) yeah it doesn't. I tried multiple queries and all it returns is the first row twice.

Comment: Just add a comment under the answer I will automatically get a message in my inbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are only processing ONE result row from your result set.

But because you are using `mysqli_fetch_array` without any parameter you get an assoc array and a numeric array so this one row as an array looks like

```
$array = ['class'=>'Class-1', '0' => 'Class-1'];
```

Hence the output you are getting.

If you want the output you suggest I would do

```
// select all the classes and names
$query = "select class,name from names order by class, name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$classes = [];  // add the names into an array
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    //load the classes names into seperate occurances of the array
    // now if you actually have 100 classes it will still work
    $classes[$row['class']][] = $row['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Now in your HTML you can do

```
<?php
foreach ( $classes as $class ) {
    echo implode('<br>', $class) . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm new to mysql so I don't really know much... How exactly could I get all rows from the result set and put them in an array so I can loop through them?

Comment: the code worked up until the foreach, then it gives a Warning saying "Array to string conversion". What should I do?

Comment: Hmm, what have I done wrong ... looking

Comment: Array ( [class-1] => Array ( [0] => John
[1] => Mark
) [class-2] => Array ( [0] => Isabel
[1] => Gabriel
[2] => Mike
) )

Comment: Ok, that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a *"select class, count(*) as classCount from names group by class order by class"*, then join it with your people list on class

| Name | Class | classCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Class-1 | 2 |
| Isabel | Class-2 | 3 |
| Isabel | Class-1 | 2 |
| Mark | Class-2 | 3 |
| Gabriel | Class-2 | 3 |

Name    Class
John    Class-1
Isabel  Class-2
Mark    Class-1
Gabriel Class-2
Mike    Class-2

Comment: Why, did the OP say they wanted a count?

Comment: I'm fairly new to mysql, so if you don't mind showing me what you mean by 'join it'? I remember seeing something like that, but I don't exactly know what it does or how to use it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I guess a foreach would resolve it better actually.